# Js Player for Wordpress margin problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, shoutcast

I'm using js player in wordpress, but I am trying insert the player in a widget area 200 by 200.
But the plugin code let a big margin on top and botton and my widget windows get bigger. How can I make my video area 200, by 200 with no margin?

This is the code generate by the plugins:

```
[videojs mp4="http://162.243.228.90:8038/;stream.mp4" poster="http://laligaderaradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/HEADER-LIGADERA-FB1.jpg" id="player1"]
```

Comment: better provide some more details or JS fiddle..!

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried.